# Unable to set duplicateFileMode property in application.yaml for liquibase

Tags: java, spring-boot, parameter-passing, liquibase, application.properties

I have a Java project with Liquibase library as database migration tool.
When running migrations I'm facing the issue:
"Found 2 files with the path 'db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'"
and a suggestion how to fix that:
"You can limit the search path to remove duplicates with the liquibase.searchPath setting. Or, if you KNOW these are the exact same file you can set liquibase.duplicateFileMode=WARN."

I am able to set the property via **static block** like:

```
static {
      System.setProperty("liquibase.duplicateFileMode", "WARN");
    }
```

And that works fine.
However, based on liquibase [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/working-with-command-parameters.html), this should we set as Java property as well, I suppose this value should be set from **application.yaml** like this:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      duplicate-file-mode: WARN
```

or

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      duplicateFileMode: WARN
```

The application fails with the initial error:
"Found 2 files with the path 'db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'"

Answer (score 2):

Other walkaround may be to apply this env variable in gradle

I added configuration to my `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
  tasks.withType<Test> {
    environment("LIQUIBASE_DUPLICATE_FILE_MODE", "WARN") // because of bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301370/unable-to-set-duplicatefilemode-property-in-application-yaml-for-liquibase
  }
```

EDIT:

Does not work for all versions of `liquibase-core`

- didn't work for `4.17.1`, worked fine for `4.20.0`

Answer (score 1):

That's an open issue in Liquibase project.
Link to follow
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3230